# Why was Kou too heavy for Moka at age 11?

Tags: rosario-vampire

Moka was always cited as being stronger than Kokoa who easily lifts the Transformer Bat Kou despite weighing 200 lbs. In one of the *Capu2* chapters, OUTER Moka is turned into a kid and swings Kou around easily. But in a flashback of Moka's eleventh birthday, Moka can’t lift Kou and indirectly tells Kokoa she’s stronger than her. What?

Actually, Moka's strength tends to fluctuate at different points also.